Enable exceptions and rtti in NDK v26.2
I have a problem with building a project in android studio that uses ndk v26.2. When the process is trying to build the c++ code, it seems to use the -fno-exceptions anf -fno-rtti flags by default. Becuase, I have "try... catch" statements in my code, the build fails.
I tried the following:
add -fexceptions flag in the CMakeLists.txt :
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -fexceptions")

add -fexceptions flag in the build.gradle file:
externalNativeBuild {
            cmake {
                cppFlags.addAll(["-fexceptions"])
            }
  }

None of the above work, because in the build command the -fno-exceptions flag shows up after -fexpections
Your help is appreciated

We haven't seen your entire CMakeLists.txt. For all we know, maybe one of your targets is adding -fno-exceptions and fno-rtti later on.

That could be it, I'm adding tflite and opencv as target link libraries. I'm sure tflite is not adding the flags. But, opencv might be. I'll check that. Thank you
